# how to play SIP RTP packets

Tags: sip, rtp, julius-speech

I'm working on windows, trying to make one application in .NET that capture the RTP SIP traffic information, and send it to julius for word detection, example if the person at the line says "one" julius can detect based on the grammar file the word "one", two, three, etc.
Testing with microphone input, julius goes fine, and the detection works like a charm. My problem is that the audio will not come from microphone anymore, because it will come from RTP sip call. So, how can I pass the RTP audio packets from network to julius input? Maybe if I can convert the RTP to audio on the fly and pass it to microphone input so julius can make the detection?

Comment: You should add some code snippet that how you are sending microphone output to julius.

Answer (score 0):

The Stereo mix device might help you. This is a tricky device which allows any app to record what you are playing.
Just playback to this device from your app and configure julius to listen on this device (or set this as the default device).

You can find the details about how to enable the stereo mix device [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/39532/how-to-enable-stereo-mix-in-windows-7-to-record-audio/).